# I need help, I try to add a search bar in my ios app that works with Cloudkit

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I'm new to the world of swift and I've been using this language for a short time.
My question is how to put a SearchBar in my application that uses Cloudkit, and the truth is I don't know how to do it, the Searchbars that I miss right now only work with CoreData

```
   var prodsArray = [CoreSave]()

var searchController:UISearchController!
    var searchResult = [CoreSave]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Buscar  Descripcion"
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive {
            return searchResult.count
        } else {
            return self.prodsArray.count
        }
    }

func filterContextForSearchTxt(searchText:String) {
        searchResult = prodsArray.filter({
            (prods: CoreSave) -> Bool in
            let nameMatch = prods.descripsiob?.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
            return nameMatch  != nil
        })
    }
```

With this code, I am implementing Search Bar within my application, but I want it to work so that it searches within cloudkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay developing against iOS 13 beta, Apple has created a CoreData adapter to be used with CloudKit. TBD I haven't looked at it yet. Check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

When I was building a backend on CloudKit, I'd do searching using a CKQuery with a specially crafted NSPredicate to look up on the object model for specific fields.

From a design standpoint, be sure to take care how often to send your query. Apple can and will throttle you if you're too chatty with queries and requests.

For example, don't bog down CloudKit by executing a new query every time a character changes. You could implement something like every 3 characters or every pause of more than x seconds from last character entry.

Sorry I don't have any code to share off hand, but half the battle is knowing the right classes. Hope this helps.